# Speed of JQM Textarea

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am still working my way through JQM so forgive me if this is an easy question.

I have the following JQM code I am working on but the issue I am noticing is when i try to drag the textarea down, it appears to be a bit slow in response:

JQ

```
$(function() {
    $("#textbox").each(function() {
        var input = '#' + this.id;
        counter(input);
        $(this).keyup(function() {
            counter(input);
        });
    });
});

function counter(field) {
    var number = 0;
    var text = $(field).val();
    var word = $(field).val().split(/[ \n\r]/);
    words = word.filter(function(word) {
        return word.length > 0 && word.match(/^[A-Za-z0-9]/);
    }).length;
        $('.words').text(words);
}
```

CSS:

```
#main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
}

#textbox {
    margin: 30px auto;
    max-width: 700px;
    min-width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

Below is both my code Fiddle and another Fiddle that appears to be much faster:

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6B9Ga/)

[Faster Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7b9A/7/)

Is there anything I can do to increase the response speed or provide link to anywhere similar question had been asked.

Thanks

Comment: Using jQM 1.4.1, there does not seem to be any delay: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8wCF4/ (only tested in Chrome desktop)

Answer (score 0):

The best I could do was to add **data-role="none"** and that solved it even though the glow isn't well pronounced. See below:

```
<label for="textbox"> </label>
<textarea data-role="none" placeholder="Simply type, or copy and paste your text or article in here" name="addwords" id="textbox"></textarea>
```